# spring @Cacheable clarification required on implementation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

I am fairly new to using the @Cacheable annotation. I have a question about the way I am implementing it.

In my application I have the following...

```
public class LovCodeDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements LovDao {

private static final String CODE_LOV_SQL = 
    " SELECT  " +
    "   code, " +
    "   code_desc value" +
    " FROM repman.code_detail  " +
    " WHERE code_type=?  " +
    " ORDER BY code_seq ";

    @Cacheable(value = "lovs", key = "#code")
    public Map<String, String> getLov(String code) {        

        Map<String, String> codes =                 
            (Map<String, String>) getJdbcTemplate()
                .query(
                    CODE_LOV_SQL
                    ,new Object[]{code} 
                    ,new LovMapExtractor());    

        return codes;
    }
}
```

This method us used to retrieve a number of different list of values from the db. For example from different places in my code this method is called with AA or BB or CC. What I am trying to achieve is for each different map to be stored in the cache under a different key.

So my question is whenever I pass in a different key will spring store the Map in a different cache? Or will it overwrite the same cache each time? If it is not working how I desire, what would I have to do to make it work the way I want to.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned in the official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), the way you have used `@Cacheable` will result in Spring using `code` as the cache key.

That means that when you call the method with `"AA"` the first time, Spring will execute the method normally and store the resulting map under the key `"AA"` in the cache. Subsequent call with `"AA"` will return the result from the cache.

When you call the method with `"BB"`, since no entry of that key is present in the cache, Spring will again execute the method and store the result in the cache under the key `"BB"` regardless of what is already in the cache under different keys.

In conclusion, the way you have configured your cache is correct.
I could however be simplified even more and look like

`@Cacheable("lovs")`

since the Spring will automatically use the argument to the method as the key to the cache